# Eigenvector localizaiton

Tags: eigenvector, matrix-theory, localization

I have raised this sort of question [before](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98025/concentration-for-eigenvectors) but I think that now I've found a better term for the subject, one which might ring more bells for people - hence the repost. Hope you won't be too angry with me.

I am interested in eigenvector localization for deterministic matrices. There is a whole body of work on the random matrix setup but I am interested in bounding the ratio between eigenvector coordinates of certain fixed and messy matrices. Any results out there that you know of pertaining to this? (I know the [old masters' work](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zbmath/?index_=2804942&type_=pdf) on positive/nonnegative matrices but need to handle further cases).

Answer (score 1):

some pointers on eigenvector localization, mainly in the context of Perron-Frobenius theory (which in view of your earlier post seems to be what you are looking for):

[Principal eigenvectors of irregular graphs](http://emis.u-strasbg.fr/journals/ELA/ela-articles/articles/vol16_pp366-379.pdf)

[Perron-frobenius theory for a generalized eigenproblem](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081089508818429)

[Bounds for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a nonnegative matrix which involve a measure of irreducibility](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0124002)

[A remark on Minc's maximal eigenvector bound for positive matrices](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479893242585)

[Einschließung des positiven eigenvektors einer nichtnegativen, irreduziblen matrix](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379573800060)

Comment: Almost - I am trying to extend the results to the mixed-sign case. (Actually, it's slightly more complicated than that - I have a monotone matrix whose smallest eigenvector I am interested in; all the Perron-Frobenius theory applies to the inverse but the inverse is difficult to compute explicitly. That's why I keep looking for a way to obtain similar results for the original matrix)